# Consistent biblatex citation numbering when using subfiles

Tags: biblatex, subfiles

I am using `subfiles` to split my project in individual parts. For the bibliography I am using `biblatex`. I only want a single bibliography for the whole document. But would like the citation references to always show the same numbers, independent if I compile the whole document or only parts of it.

The `main.tex` file is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\begin{document}

\cite{aksin}
\cite{weinberg}
\cite{angenendt}

\subfile{subfile.tex}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

```
[1] [2] [3] % from the main file
[1] [4] [3] % from the subfile
```

The `subfile.tex` is:

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\cite{aksin}
\cite{yoon}
\cite{angenendt}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

```
[1] [2] [3]
```

Desired result:

```
[1] [4] [3]
```

I assume that I have to convince `biblatex` to read its information always from the `main.aux` but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: The order of the citation in the main file is as expected 1,2,3,1,4,3. The problem is the subfile on its own, as it is not aware of the previous citation in the main file and therefore produces inconsistent citation numbering if compared to the global bibliography. I was sloppy with the naming convention of the files, I have clearified that the main file should be called `main.tex` and the subfile `subfile.tex` and that the references within the code must match the file name,

Comment: The manual says the subfiles use the *preamble* of the main file to compile. The subfile won't see the cites in the document body of the main file. That is why you want to read the main aux. I understand now.

Comment: The `.bbl` files produced are different - search for `\entry`: the main one has 4 entries, the subfile's one has 3 entries. Your question, I think, resolves into: "How to merge different .bbl files?" It sounds possible, since they are structured text.

Comment: After running biber on the subfile, manually copy/rename the main `.bbl` to become the subfile `.bbl`, then run latex on the subfile, and 1,4,3 comes out. If it can be done manually, it can be done programatically. (A future package option, perhaps?)

Comment: That sounds like a nice way to go ahead.

Comment: It works for me only when I copy the `.aux` instead of the `.bbl`, but the effect is just as you have described.